# ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\username\package.json' when need to run docker and nodejs

Tags: node.js, docker

i need to build image from nodejs project . but when i run this command :

`docker run image-name`

it show me this error :

```
     C:\Users\username\package.json
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Users\username\package.json'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
```

this is my docker file :

```
FROM node:14.16.1
ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /
COPY ["package.json", "package-lock.json*", "./"]
RUN  npm cache clean --force && npm install 
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD npm run start
```

and this is package.json :

```
    {
  "name": "Profile",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rimraf dist && tsc",
    "preserve": "npm run build",
    "serve": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development concurrently \"tsc --watch\" \"nodemon -q dist/index.js\"",
    "prestart": "npm run build",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node dist/index.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/body-parser": "^1.19.1",
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "helmet": "^4.6.0",
    "mongoose": "^5.13.7",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/express": "^4.17.13",
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.11.97",
    "@types/node": "^16.7.1",
    "concurrently": "^6.2.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12",
    "ts-node": "^10.2.1",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  }
}
```

**whats the problem ?? how can i solve this problem ??**
**Edit**

**OS** : Windows 10

**Command For Build Image :** docker build -tag profile-srv

**Project Structure :**

[image]

Comment: Add 1. the host OS, 2. the app folders structure 3. The container OS, 4. The command for build the image

Comment: @Max i edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess:

```
FROM node:14.16.1
ENV NODE_ENV=production
WORKDIR /
COPY package.json .
COPY package-lock.json* .
RUN npm cache clean --force 
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD npm run start
```